# How to parse an Jsonobject to string (swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift

My program receives the following JSON array from an API

```
[{
   Direccion = "";
   Imagen = hospital;
   Nombre = "Centro Antirr\U00e1bico Municipal(S.S.A.)";
   Telefono = "(52)(222) 220 15 94";
}, {
   Direccion = "";
   Imagen = hospital;
   Nombre = "Rescate y Primeros Auxilios de Puebla ";
   Telefono = "";
}, {
   Direccion = "";
   Imagen = policia;
   Nombre = "Denuncia ciudadana an\U00f3nima";
   Telefono = 089;
}]
```

I want to put all that into an array in order for me to use it to fill a tableview. I've try to parse it to string but I a get this error

```
"Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x10693f418) to 'NSString'"
```

Heres my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelAPI: UILabel!


let sections = ["Directorio"]
var arreAPI: [String] = []

    do {
            let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [Any]
            //let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as! [[String: Any]]

            DispatchQueue.main.async { // Correct
                self.arreAPI=todo as! [String]
                self.labelAPI?.text = todo[5] as? String
            }
    } catch  {
            print("Error al convertir data a JSON")
            //return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: You have an array of dictionaries not an array of strings. `self.arreAPI = todo as? [[String: Any]] ?? []`

Comment: Thanks it work just had to change the type frome my array from String to Any. 

However it I can not display the information ether in the label or my table view. Do I need to change something?

Comment: You could have already cast it when serialising it  `let dictionaries = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as? [[String:Any]] ?? []`

Comment: then you can iterate over your dictionaries `for dictionary in dictionaries {`

Comment: If you are coding in Swift 4 you should structure your data and parse your JSON using the Codable protocol

Answer (score 1):

The String you provide superficially looks like JSON, but it does not conform to the [spec](http://www.json.org), so if that is really what you get from your API then you will be in trouble to find a JSON-parser accepting it. In light of the `Codable` protocol I defined

```
struct Directorio :Codable {
    let Direccion : String
    let Imagen : String
    let Nombre : String
    let Telefono : String
}
```

which allowed me to encode and print a valid JSON-object as follows:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let dir = Directorio(Direccion: "", Imagen: "hospital",
                     Nombre: "Centro Antirr\u{00e1}bico Municipal(S.S.A.)", 
                     Telefono: "(52)(222) 220 15 94")
let dirData = try! encoder.encode(dir)
print(String(data: dirData, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

this will print

```
{"Nombre":"Centro Antirrábico Municipal(S.S.A.)","Direccion":"","Telefono":"(52)(222) 220 15 94","Imagen":"hospital"}
```

which demonstrates how your JSON-string should really be structured. Making the necessary corrections you can parse it as follows:

```
let res = """
[{
    "Direccion" : "",
    "Imagen" : "hospital",
    "Nombre" : "Centro Antirr\u{00e1}bico Municipal(S.S.A.)",
    "Telefono" : "(52)(222) 220 15 94"
}, {
    "Direccion" : "",
    "Imagen" : "hospital",
    "Nombre" : "Rescate y Primeros Auxilios de Puebla ",
    "Telefono" : ""
}, {
    "Direccion" : "",
    "Imagen" : "policia",
    "Nombre" : "Denuncia ciudadana an\u{00f3}nima",
    "Telefono" : "089",
}]
"""

let jsonData = res.data(using: .utf8)!
let decodr = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let todo = try decodr.decode([Directorio].self, from: jsonData)
    print(todo[2].Telefono)
} catch {
    print("error on decode: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

This is still a quick and dirty example, since there are better ways to convert your upper case JSON-keys to lower case Swift-style properties, but that would just clutter the issue. I am afraid you will have to get your JSON straight, otherwise the (excellent) Swift JSON-support won't be of much help to you.

Comment: Hey @Patru I see what you meen and it's something I hadn't noticed the JSON it's correct but I think the way I consume the API  with     
    let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [Any] some how changes the structure of the JSON. Thats way I get it with "=" instead of the ":".

Comment: I found this tutorial which does exactly want I'm trying to do display the info on a tableview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNkS_QIngg8. And it's similar to what you did. I follow the tutorial and works fine but when I did it with my API it works I can print in the console the struct but I can not show the text in the table view.

Comment: As always on StackOverflow: Please post the `code` you are using, your expectation of what it _should_ be doing and where it _fails_ to do what you expect. This will lead to a question we can answer. As to the above: Please post the _exact string_ you get from your API, if you think your way of parsing is responsible for your problems. In general the way of consuming the interface is _not_ the problem, but I might be wrong on this one. Anyways: please get us closer to _the code_.

Comment: here is my code github.com/jimmycardoso/firsJASONtry/blob/master/… I follow your advice about the Codable protocol and dis this: github.com/jimmycardoso/JSONtry/blob/master/CARPEAPITableView/…. which is easier cleaner and I understand it better.

Comment: Now, that is certainly some code, but it completely covers up your question. Please let us know what part of the code you have troubles with and post an _actual_ String (in a form that transfers well to a Playground) as returned by your web service (similar to what I provided above). Given that I am sure we can work out how to parse your JSON. And by the way: Do you control your WebService too (i.e. you can change its structure) or is it a "given"?

Comment: @JimC. I finally noticed what you have managed to do. Using `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` lets the parser decide what objects it wants to create, in Swift you can either cast it to a `[String:Any]` `Dictionary` or an `NSDictionary`. After casting to `NSDictionary` it will print as the property-list like structure you had in your post. So parsing your JSON was never the problem. However given your code I _really_ had a lot of problems guessing _what_ that was.

Comment: Given you load your data asynchronously in your `viewDidLoad` you could end up with a race condition where your `cellForRowAt` method is called before your data is actually present. It is difficult to tell without knowing more about the kind of Error you are getting.